# How to extract multiple values from an array by indexes in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, subset, element

I have indices in data frame columns and would like to extract elements of an array based on these indices, hopefully with a simple subset function?

I have a 3D array (but applicable for any number of dimensions) 
For example:

```
a<-array(1:27,dim = c(3,3,3))
```

I can extract a single element

```
a[1,2,3]
[1] 22
```

I would like to extract multiple elements given their indices. 
Say I want for example elements (1,2,3)= 22, (2,2,3)= 23, and (3,1,1)=3 that are given in a table/dataframe format:

```
coords <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,2,3), c(3,1,1)))
colnames(coords) <- c("index1","index2","index3")
coords

  index1 index2 index3
1      1      2      3
2      2      2      3
3      3      1      1
```

For a call (doesn't work)

```
a[coords$index1,coords$index2,coords$index3]
```

I would expect (but no luck) the output of this call to be similar to a vector

```
c(a[1,2,3],a[2,2,3],a[3,1,1])
[1] 22 23  3
```

I could obviously loop through these indices but I feel like there is something I'm missing.. there should be something simpler/better.

I've tried multiple things and searches but I haven't found anything that works, so apologies if this was answered somewhere already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost right! you may use the following code:

```
a<-array(1:27,dim = c(3,3,3))
coords <- cbind(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,2,3), c(3,1,1)))
colnames(coords) <- c("index1","index2","index3")
coords
a[coords]
```

The difference is the use of `cbind` instead of `as.data.frame` and the way you access the 3d matrix position with `coords`.

Summing up, it must be a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame/list` to be able to access the content of `a`.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: You can convert to matrix `a[as.matrix(coords)]` from the initial dataframe

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the tip! Summing up, it must be a matrix instead of a data.frame or a list, right? :)

Comment: Thank you both! Solved my problem! 
As an extension of this question: if the coords matrix contains strings which are (dimname) indexes per dimension, instead of simple integer indexes would this approach work? Or do you need to use the integer matrix

Comment: @user2829168 I think it shoud be numbers. You may convert chr matrix to numeric with this: `class(coords) <- "numeric"`